# Check products in cart if they are out of stock before place order REST API : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, api, rest-api, out-of-stock

I am building mobile application using `Magento 2`, I had an old defined cart which had a product and when checking out it gives an error saying `the item is out of stock`, that happened after payment and placing the order. I checked this product in backend and found its `Quantity was 0 and out of stock`. checked with my friend and knew that he bought it in a test case.

Ho can I fix this problem and check all products in cart are in stock **OR** out of stock Using REST API?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question but you can add a new extension attributes that check stock status in `rest/V1/carts/mine/items`  and display the appropriate message.

Create your extension attribute in `Vendor/ModuleName/etc/webapi_rest/extension_attributes.xml`

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
    <attribute code="stock" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
```

Then Create your plugin to overwrite `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository::getList`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository">
        <plugin name="stock" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Stock" disabled="false" sortOrder="70"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then Create Stock.php in `Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Stock.php`

In Stock.php, we overwrite GetList with aroundplugin. We also get StockRegistryInterface to check If item is in stock by sku. Then we pass the message to our extension interface factory.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository as ItemRepository;

class Stock
{
    protected $quoteRepository;
    protected $cartItemExtensionFactory;
    protected $stockRegistry;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionFactory $cartItemExtensionFactory,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->cartItemExtensionFactory = $cartItemExtensionFactory;
    }

    public function aroundGetList(ItemRepository $subject, \Closure $proceed, $cartId)
    {
        $cartItems = $proceed($cartId);
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes */
          $i = 0;
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $extensionAttributes = $cartItems[$i]->getExtensionAttributes();
            if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
                $extensionAttributes = $this->cartItemExtensionFactory->create();
            }
            $sku = $item->getSku();
            $stock = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku)->getIsInStock();
            if ($stock) {
                $message = "Item In Stock";
            } else {
                $message = "Item Out Of Stock";
            }
            $extensionAttributes->setStock($message);
            $cartItems[$i]->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
            $i++;
        }
       // $cartItems->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $cartItems;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i think we can use a boolean flag <attribute code="stock" type="boolean" />  if ($stock) {
                $message = true;
            } else {
                $message = false;
            }

Comment: Thanks @sivakumar. Boolean is obviously better. But this still return a string of "0" and "1". Any reason for this??

Comment: This code give error :Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtension::setStock() in /Vendor/CheckStock/Plugin/Stock.php:46 @SoladogunIlyasAdemuyiwa

Comment: @LovelySetia Make sure you recompile. It should generate that attribute setStock in the generated folder since  attribute code is stock

Comment: I will  deleted var/generation/*,var/page_cache/*,var/cache/*.After that run Setup:upgrade,setup:di:compile,setup:static-content:deploy commands.It still showing error @SoladogunIlyasAdemuyiwa

Comment: @LovelySetia, Did you put your extension attributes code?? <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
    <attribute code="stock" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>

Comment: @SoladogunIlyasAdemuyiwa Yes,Please look here " https://pastebin.com/KHB799pQ" for extension_attributes.

Comment: @LovelySetia, I just tried your code in Magento 2.2.6 and its working fine. This is the code its generated at generated/code/Magento/Quote/Api/Data/CartItemExtension.php in https://pastebin.com/xsBrN6Ez

Comment: I am using magento-2.1.12.@SoladogunIlyasAdemuyiwa

Comment: @LovelySetia instead of Vendor/ModuleName/etc/webapi_rest/extension_attributes.xml put here Vendor/ModuleName/etc/extension_attributes.xml